# Word count of a file with haskell

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, functional-programming, hugs

I have a problem with Haskell when i am trying to count the words of a file. I am just a beginner and this is my first program so i am pretty sure that it is a very simple mistake. 
I am using hugs to run my code. Until now i learnt how to read from a file but i failed to count the words in it. My code is something like this

```
main = do {
contents <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt";
let contents2 = replace"."""contents;
let contents3 = replace"!"""contents2;
let lower = map toLower contents3;
let chop = words(lower);
let count = show(length chop)++"\n";
putStrln $"This file has"++count++"words";
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `readFile "file" >>= print . length . words` but you should learn some haskell before (follow some tutorial http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: It worked perfectly. I will follow the tutorial. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either one of the following:

```
main = readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . words
```

or

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
    print . length . words $ contents
```

Comment: So do we use the same logic when we try to find any characters? Are there any shortcut methods for that too??

Comment: I tried a code like this but gave an error for the letter "s". What is the reason for the error?

readFile "/tmp/foo.txt">>= print . length . filter s ;

Comment: Are you looking for total number of a specific character? You may use       `readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" >>= print . length . filter (== 's')`.